# CF7 Form File Upload to FTP Servers Based on Dropdown Selection

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp, contact-form-7

I have a simple request form setup in Contact Form 7 with a dropdown selection of two facilities. There are two anonymous server addresses to upload files to based on which dropdown facility is selected. I have successfully added the following code to the functions.php file, tested it and it works correctly for one of the dropdown selections. My problem is, I cannot get the code right for the other dropdown selection to upload and work correctly.

The setup is the form part goes to a distributed email address and the file gets uploaded to the Anaheim or Orange FTP server.

ftp**.domain.com – Orange Facility ftp**.domain.com – Anaheim Facility

This only works for the Orange Facility. Now I can't seem to get the logic right for the 2nd code. I tried doing two separate functions (FacilityA and FacilityB) but I am stuck on how to take the "SelectAFacility" name and split it into 2 functions.

[select SelectAFacility "Anaheim|ftpuploadanaheim@domain.com Orange|ftpuploadorange@domain.com"]

I was told at WordPress StackExchange that the question was off-topic so I posted it here. Any help would be great!

Here's the code:

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'log_cf7');
function log_cf7($WPCF7_ContactForm) {

    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $data = $submission->get_posted_data();
    $uploadedFiles = $submission->uploaded_files();

$location = $data['SelectAFacility'];

    if(isset($uploadedFiles) && isset($uploadedFiles['your-file'])){

$ftp_server="ftp**.domain.com";
$ftp_username="username";
$ftp_userpass="password";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

$fileToUpload =     $uploadedFiles['your-file'];
$remotefile = $_FILES['your-file']['name'];

    if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, $remotefile, $fileToUpload, FTP_ASCII))
 {
    //echo "Successfully uploaded $remotefile.";
  }
    else
 {
    // echo "Error uploading $fileToUpload.";
  }
   // close connection
   ftp_close($ftp_conn);
 }
 }
```

Comment: Are you just wanting to upload to different FTP address based on the what the user selects in `SelectAFacility` ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

So just add a simple conditional statement based on the value of `SelectAFacility`:

```
if ($location == 'Facility A') {
        $ftp_server = "ftp**.domainA.com";
        $ftp_username = "username A";
        $ftp_userpass = "password A";
    } elseif ($location == 'Facility B') {
        $ftp_server = "ftp**.domainB.com";
        $ftp_username = "username B";
        $ftp_userpass = "password B";
    } else {
        // do something for unknown facility if you want
    }
}
```

all together:

```
function log_cf7($WPCF7_ContactForm)
{
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $data = $submission->get_posted_data();
    $uploadedFiles = $submission->uploaded_files();

    $location = $data['SelectAFacility'];

    if (isset($uploadedFiles) && isset($uploadedFiles['your-file'])) {

        if ($location == 'Facility A') {
            $ftp_server = "ftp**.domainA.com";
            $ftp_username = "username A";
            $ftp_userpass = "password B";
        } elseif ($location == 'Facility B') {
            $ftp_server = "ftp**.domainB.com";
            $ftp_username = "username B";
            $ftp_userpass = "password B";
        } else {
            // do something for unknown facility if you want
            exit();
        }

        $ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to server");
        $login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

        $fileToUpload = $uploadedFiles['your-file'];
        $remotefile = $_FILES['your-file']['name'];

        if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, $remotefile, $fileToUpload, FTP_ASCII)) {
            //echo "Successfully uploaded $remotefile.";
        } else {
            // echo "Error uploading $fileToUpload.";
        }
        // close connection
        ftp_close($ftp_conn);
    }
}
```

Comment: So would I need to keep the original code and just add the conditional statement?

Comment: Essentially, YES.  If your code already worked, you just use the conditional to set the values of the FTP info to the correct values based on the `$location`

Comment: Then you are using the exact same working code, with only different FTP credentials.

Comment: Okay, I've tried this several different ways and can't get it to work. I changed the locations to ($location == 'Anaheim') and ($location == 'Orange') to match the dropdown selection, but it still isn't working. 
       <label> Select A Facility </label>
                  [select SelectAFacility "Anaheim|ftp**domainA.com" 
                  "Orange|ftp**domainB.com"]